# Installing a second WP database for use in MAMP

Tags: wordpress, installation, mamp

I'm still new to this so please be gentle :)

After a lot of head-scratching, I finally got MAMP installed and set up so I can create a Wordpress site offline to mess about with. However, I'm now in a position where I want to design a site for a friend offline using the same process but without damaging the site I'm already creating for myself.

What steps must I take to install Wordpress again and get it set up as a fresh site that I can use with MAMP? I am confused that the url for the local site will be the same in the address bar. Could someone please explain in very simple terms what to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry bro, But you can only have one instance of wordpress running on one server. (Offline or Online). I think what you should be seeking to do is to have multiple websites on single wordpress installation. Check the docs at [www.wordpress.org](http://www.wordpress.org) for more info.

Comment: i'm running 20 sites locally for a development process :)

Answer (score 0):

You have MAMP main folder for sites (documentroot)

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs
```

where you put separate sites
so if you have

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site1
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site2
```

the addresses for sites will be

```
http://localhost:8888/site1
http://localhost:8888/site2
```

so all you need to do is to copy wordpress to a new folder and setup database for a new site.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Just one question. Where should I copy Wordpress from and how would I setup a new database? Should I simply run the Wordpress installer again?

Comment: download wordpress from here https://wordpress.org/download/ create a new database here http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin/?lang=en and run your wordpress installer again.